# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to solve this kind of probe help me.

```
Select SUM(iamount) 
from cust_installment 
where  c_no=(
    Select b.c_no 
    from a_basic a 
        INNER JOIN cust_personal b ON a.a_code=b.a_code
        INNER JOIN cust_installment c ON b.c_no=c.c_no  
    where c.idate BETWEEN '2014-06-25' AND '2014-06-25')
```

error is

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Is it in MSSQL, MySQL or other context? What of the results of your subquery do you want to use, when it returns more than one value?

Comment: @ schlonzo : It is SQL SERVER.

Comment: You could use `(Select TOP 1 b.c_no from a_basic a INNER JOIN cust_personal b ON a.a_code=b.a_code INNER JOIN cust_installment c ON b.c_no=c.c_no  where c.idate BETWEEN '2014-06-25' AND '2014-06-25')` for your subquery, but I don't know if that's the wanted result.

Comment: What is the required outcome with the WHERE clause? Do you require the c_no to be an exact match to a c_no in the second query or do you require where the c_no is in a list of c_no's in the secondary select query? The context is not quite clear.

Comment: a_basic table what's the significance of adding this ?Is column iamount from this table?

Answer (score 2):

In your main where clause you have `where  c_no=( <<SUBQUERY>> )`. The inner subquery here must return a single result, otherwise that where-clause doesn't make sense.

So either restrict the subquery to a single result by using `top 1` or by fixing it if logically it should only ever return a single result.

Alternatively, if you're expecting to match multiple results, change the main where clause to  `where c_no in ( <<SUBQUERY>> )`

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery

```
Select b.c_no from a_basic a INNER JOIN cust_personal b ON a.a_code=b.a_code INNER JOIN cust_installment c ON b.c_no=c.c_no  where c.idate BETWEEN '2014-06-25' AND '2014-06-25'
```

can return more than one value.

You have several opportunities:

1. Use Select TOP 1 b.c_no from a_basic a INNER JOIN...
2. Replace the `=` with `in`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select SUM(iamount) 
from cust_installment 
where  c_no in (
    Select b.c_no 
    from a_basic a 
        INNER JOIN cust_personal b ON a.a_code=b.a_code
        INNER JOIN cust_installment c ON b.c_no=c.c_no  
    where c.idate BETWEEN '2014-06-25' AND '2014-06-25')
```