# SQL Server EXEC @SQL command causing an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, command, exec

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM
        (SELECT [Domain], [Server], [Instance], [DatabaseName] 
         FROM [dbo].[OF_Databases_A]
         INTERSECT 
         SELECT [Domain], [Server], [Instance], [DatabaseName] 
         FROM [dbo].[OF_Databases]) z) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL=  
    (
    select 'Delete from [dbo].[OF_Databases] where domain='''+[Domain]+'''' + ' and server= '''+[Server] +'''' + ' and instance= '''+[Instance] +'''' + ' and DatabaseName= '''+[DatabaseName] +''''  + ' GO' from [dbo].[OF_Databases_A] 
    INTERSECT 
    select 'Delete from [dbo].[OF_Databases] where domain='''+[Domain]+'''' + ' and server= '''+[Server] +'''' + ' and instance= '''+[Instance] +'''' + ' and DatabaseName= '''+[DatabaseName] +''''  + ' GO'  from [dbo].[OF_Databases] 
    ) 

    EXECUTE @SQL
END
```

If I execute this query, I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 81
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 87
> Could not find stored procedure ''.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Visit this article, may be it will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755137/msg-512-level-16-state-1-line-2-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is

Comment: “Subquery returned more than 1 value” — so fix it?

Comment: The subquery here is `set @sql = (subquery)`; however, a scalar can only hold one value. Running the subquery by itself will show the entire (unexpected) result. The flowing exec “fails” because the @sql variable is NULL. Turn on [xact_abort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql) to have the tsql stop at the first failure (which in this case is due to the subquery returning 2 or more rows).

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL at all here. Looks like you could just use a `DELETE` with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Agreed I see no need for dynamic SQL, and if you did need it you should pass through the parameters properly using `sp_executesql` and escape object names correctly using `QUOTENAME`

Comment: To be honest, the code makes no sense anyway: you are creating a `DELETE` statement for every row in the table, you may as well remove the `WHERE`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your variable could take only one value, you are giving it a resultSet, for it to work you need to do like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM
        (SELECT [Domain], [Server], [Instance], [DatabaseName] 
         FROM [dbo].[OF_Databases_A]
         INTERSECT 
         SELECT [Domain], [Server], [Instance], [DatabaseName] 
         FROM [dbo].[OF_Databases]) z) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(max) = ''

    SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ISNULL(QUERY, '') + ' '
FROM 
    (
    select 'Delete from [dbo].[OF_Databases] where domain='''+[Domain]+'''' + ' and server= '''+[Server] +'''' + ' and instance= '''+[Instance] +'''' + ' and DatabaseName= '''+[DatabaseName] +''''  + ' GO' AS QUERY from [dbo].[OF_Databases_A] 
        INTERSECT 
        select 'Delete from [dbo].[OF_Databases] where domain='''+[Domain]+'''' + ' and server= '''+[Server] +'''' + ' and instance= '''+[Instance] +'''' + ' and DatabaseName= '''+[DatabaseName] +''''  + ' GO'  from [dbo].[OF_Databases] 
        ) a

    EXECUTE (@SQL)
END
```

Comment: FYI, this'll result in `@SQL` having the value `NULL`. `NULL + {literal string}` = `NULL`.

Comment: @Larnu good remark, i updated the answer to prevent this from happening.

Comment: It'll still result in `NULL`, @DouraydTLILI . `@SQL` isn't set a value prior to you concatenating it to itself, so `SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ...` would result in `NULL + ...` for the first iteration, and then would result in `NULL` *every* iteration. really, however, you shouldn't be using such syntax, it's a [documented anitpattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment),  and should instead be using string aggregation.

Comment: Larnu Yes i forgot to initalise the variable.
@user2864740 I know that this not the best method to delete, and this not the final answer, Rednirug should update the query to suit his needs.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, `EXECUTE @SQL` would give an error along the lines of `The name 'Delete from [dbo]...' is not a valid identifier.` You should be using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL operator, that's why, @Rednirug .